# identity server4: Why I receiving "The signature key was not found" when calling the authorized controller

Tags: model-view-controller, access-token, identity, identityserver4

Currently running an identity server 4 and able to receive the access token using client_credential flow.

I used the token to access an api from server but receive this message

> error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

I suspect that i need to validate the token somehow when passing the token when calling the web api.

My setting is like this.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiAuthorityBaseUrl");
        options.Audience = "api1";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; 
    });
```

and using AddDeveloperSigningCredential.

There is something called TokenValidationParameters in AddJwtBearer, I am not sure is it the right place to solve issue. Can someone give me some hints

Comment: Can you provide the Identity Server log output?

Answer (score 6):

The middleware (AddJwtBearer) is trying to find the signature in the `id_token` to verify with the authority - `.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks` keys. Probably your token may not have a private key signature.

Its possible in your case, the authority is from a different location (clone of the instance) which may be of same params but not the signing keys.

Comment: also possible that you may be using the wrong authority(clone running at different instance) issued token. which case the signature will be different at each authority.